# Executing Spring Initializing Beans in Parallel

Tags: java, spring, initialization

I have multiple Spring `InitializingBean` classes, which I'd like them to all run `afterPropertiesSet()` in parallel. When I run a small example, however, they are being executed synchronously. Is there any way to execute them in parallel?

Below is an example initializing bean which can be used to test out what I'm referring to. When creating multiple classes like this (i.e. `InitBeanOne`, `InitBeanTwo`, ...), the logs show that they are being run synchronously.

One idea which I had in mind was to have a single initializing bean asynchronously initialize the desired classes. This is a last resort option, though, as I'd like to take advantage of the initializing beans for each class individually, and not have other dependent classes.

```java
@Component
public class InitBean implements InitializingBean {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitBean.class);

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("BEGIN: InitBean");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        LOGGER.info("END: InitBean");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should relocate the code to an event listening method, and mark the method with `@Async`.

Make sure the Async functionality is correctly set up. See: [How To Do @Async in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async).

You should make the method be triggered when the Spring framework fires the [`ApplicationReadyEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html).

```
@Component
public class InitBean {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitBean.class);

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationReady(ApplicationReadyEvent event) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("BEGIN: onApplicationReady");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        LOGGER.info("END: onApplicationReady");
    }
}
```

*Warning:* By doing this, other methods may be called before/during the invocation of this method. If the method does any kind of initialization needed by those other methods, you need to handle that, e.g. using a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

---

**UPDATE**

If you need for the application to delay the completion of the startup sequence until all asynchronous methods have completed, I think you need to handle it yourself.

Create interface `AsyncInitializingBean` with same method as [`InitializingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html), then create a `@Component` named `AsyncBeanInitializer` auto-wiring a `AsyncInitializingBean[]` (or `List`), then have it execute all the methods using an `ExecutorService` on `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

```
@Component
public class InitBean implements AsyncInitializingBean { // <== Change interface (only change needed)

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitBean.class);

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("BEGIN: InitBean");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        LOGGER.info("END: InitBean");
    }
}
```

```
public interface AsyncInitializingBean {
    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception;
}
```

```
@Component
public class AsyncBeanInitializer {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncBeanInitializer.class);

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private AsyncInitializingBean[] beans;

    @EventListener
    public void onContextRefreshed(@SuppressWarnings("unused") ContextRefreshedEvent event) throws Exception {
        if (this.beans == null || this.beans.length == 0)
            return;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        try {
            AtomicInteger failed = new AtomicInteger();
            for (AsyncInitializingBean bean : beans) {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    try {
                        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        failed.incrementAndGet();
                        LOGGER.error("Async afterPropertiesSet() method failed: " + e, e);
                    }
                });
            }
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            if (failed.get() != 0)
                throw new RuntimeException(failed.get() + " Async afterPropertiesSet() methods failed. See log for details.");
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem! I have a concern with this suggestion, though. It starts up the application server while the beans are still being initialized. My end goal is to have all initializing beans run concurrently, and not starting up the application server until they are all finished.

Comment: I just added a warning about that. I'd recommend handling it with `CountDownLatch` in each component, so that if one component is slow, other components will still function as soon as they are done, i.e. the application will be (mostly) ready a lot quicker.

Comment: I don't think this is going to satisfy what I need. The initializing beans need to be finished before application server startup. It's not about the inter-dependency of components. Rather, I'm looking for a solution to have them all be initializing at the same time, all the while finalizing before the application can be deemed as ready to receive traffic.

I think a similar issue which is being tracked by Spring is issue [#13410](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13410).

Comment: Your latest update to your answer works as desired. +1! Would there be an `init-method` implementation of this, so as to not be dependent upon an internal interface? If not, this is the best solution to work with so far.

Comment: We have used this method of initializing beans successfully for a few years using an old spring project. After upgrading our spring to spring boot starter parent 2.7.0 our service is now allowing traffic before all the beans get initialized. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Found a way around it?